# Protecting wordpress - How to used wodb->prepare() function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, sql-injection

I am set up the below sql with `$wpdb->prepare`.  Currently this query is run in a function, and all the variables are passed to the function from my page.php file in wordpress.  The below query works.  However my question is do I need to use the `%s` on my variables for `$field1, $field2,` etc... If so can someone help me with how to set it up, it did not work when I tried.  If not, could someone tell me why not?   Thank you!

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT wp_eva_geography.$field1, wp_eva_geography.$field2 
FROM wp_eva_geography
WHERE wp_eva_geography.$field3=%s AND wp_eva_geography.$field4=%s",$type,$geo_no_dash);
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the reference document to find out how it works.

In your specific case it might be worth just echo-ing out the MySQL query string so you can see what it's actually trying to request. Then you can spot if something has gone wrong, like a bad column name or value entry.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

```
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta
         WHERE post_id = %d
          AND meta_key = %s",
         13, 'gargle' 
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion on echoing my sql.  I found it it looks like this:  <code>SELECT DISTINCT wp_eva_geography.'county_short', wp_eva_geography.county_slug</code>  So when I put %s as the field name it add the starting and ending single quote.  Is there away to prevent the single quote?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't have the column names as variables, I'd rather see them in the actual query, otherwise it's not very clear what the request does. In my experience I've only ever passed values into SQL queries.